# Firebase storage metadata not included in security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to implement Firebase Storage rules so that only a post author can create it, delete it and update it. The problem is that in simulator it works perfectly but in real case it does not. For me it seems like the metadata I use do not show up in the rules or is not included in the put request.

I do everything as written in the documentation:

- [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files)
- [put function and metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata)

These are my rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  //Posts
    match /{allImages=**} {
       allow read: if authenticated();
       allow create: if authenticated() && metadata().userId == request.auth.uid;
       allow update, delete: if authenticated() && metadata().userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
    }
  function metadata() { return request.resource.metadata; }
  function authenticated() { return request.auth.uid != null; }
}
```

And this is the function I use to upload file or files:

```
uploadFile({ commit, rootState }, payload) {
    const storageRef = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`posts/${payload.id}/${payload.index}/${payload.index}`)
    commit('app/setError', null, { root: true })
    commit('app/setLoading', true, { root: true })
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      storageRef
        .put(payload.file, {
          userId: rootState.authentication.user.id
        }) //HERE IS THE METADATA AS THE SECOND PARAMETER (userId)
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
            resolve(downloadURL)
            commit('app/setLoading', false, { root: true })
          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error)
          commit('app/setError', error, { root: true })
          commit('app/setLoading', false, { root: true })
        })
    })
  },
```

**Edit 1**: This is the object metadata I test with inside simulator:

```
{"metadata":{"userId":"9PuxRiKI17Y8hbwW9aVISpdrpZa2"},"name":"b/myprojectid-develop.appspot.com/o/posts/{postId}","bucket":"myprojectid-develop.appspot.com"}
```

and this is minified Object I post on real case as a metadata:

```
{"userId":"9PuxRiKI17Y8hbwW9aVISpdrpZa2"}
```

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you made sure that the value you're passing for userId is exactly what you expect? We can't see here what the actual value is - it's hidden behind object properties.

Comment: @DougStevenson Jep I am 100% sure that the values are what I expect them to be. I also want to mention that I tested with the same UID on real case as I did on simulator test. Why I must say I am sure about my values inside the object is that on realtime database I use security rules too and those are working perfectly. If needed I can update question with minimal object that I post with its values.

Comment: It looks like this should work.  If you have specific steps to reproduce, please file a bug report with Firebase support and see if they can reproduce.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, I did file a bug report under the link u provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did contact firebase support and the solution they gave was to wrap your metadata object inside `customMetadata` like shown below:

```
storageRef
.put(payload.file, {
   customMetadata: { //This is the required key
      userId: <your user id data>
   }
})
```

**NB!** This appears to be documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadMetadata.html#custommetadata)

Comment: Looks like it's documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadMetadata.html#custommetadata

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that, it is higly deeped in the documentation. I actually even did read this page.

Comment: Missed it myself!  Glad you got an answer.